# how to add hours and minutes in curdate mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using date_add function to add 12 hours and 30 minutes in current date.

```
 select DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL  '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE )
```

gives me 2016-01-03 12:30:00

I just need date after adding 12:30.

what is the correct way to do same?

Comment: Just use the `date` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `date` function:

```
select DATE(DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL  '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE ))
```

You can also express the logic using `ADDTIME()`:

```
SELECT DATE(ADDTIME(currdate(), TIME('12:30:00')))
```

Answer (score 1):

use NOW

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD( now( ) , INTERVAL  '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE )
```